# How to disable @Assert validation on removed widgets

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation, assert

I don't know why assert validation still applies to a widget that I removed!

I create a form

```
$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $doctor);
```

then i removed some fields from it

```
$form ->remove("picture");
$form ->remove("phone");
```

Indeed the fields are removed from the view ! but when I click on submit i still get `"@Assert\NotBlank()` error message ! on phone!

On the controller I did

```
$doctor = new User();
$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $doctor);

$form ->remove("picture");
$form ->remove("phone");
```

Here is the code of User entity (i removed getters and setters)

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"username"},
 *     message="The username is already used."
 * )
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"email"},
 *     message="The Email is already used."
 * )
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255 ,  unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255 , unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email(message="This Email is not valid ")
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255 )
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 8, max = 30,
     *      minMessage = "Your password must be between 8 and 30 characters.")
     *  @Assert\EqualTo(propertyPath = "password2", message="Passwords does not match!" )
     */
    private $password;


   /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
    *  @Assert\EqualTo(propertyPath = "password", message="Passwords does not match!" )
     */

    private $password2;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true),
     * @Assert\NotBlank(),
     * @Assert\Regex(
     * pattern="/[0-9]{8}/",
     * message="Invalid Phone number"
     * )
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $picture;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $braclet_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $is_doctor;

    /**
     * @Assert\Length(min=5, max=100)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $Full_Name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

 }
```

Here is the code of the view:

```
{{ form_start(form, {attr: {novalidate: 'novalidate'}}) }}

        {{ form_widget(form.Full_Name, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Full Name','type': 'text'} }) }}       
        {{ form_errors(form.Full_Name) }} 

        {{ form_widget(form.username,  {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Username'} }) }}      
        {{ form_errors(form.username) }} 


        {{ form_widget(form.email,  {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email Adress'} }) }}     
        {{ form_errors(form.email) }}


        {{ form_widget(form.password, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password','type': 'Password'} }) }}        
        {{ form_errors(form.password) }} 

        {{ form_widget(form.password2, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Confirm Password','type': 'Password'} }) }}       

        {{ form_errors(form.password2) }} 

        <button class="btn btn-raised g-bg-cyan waves-effect">SIGN UP</button>

{{ form_rest(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are validating your entity regardless of the fields you add or remove. In these cases you can use validation groups:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html

So for your case you could create a new group next to the "Default", for example "doctor".

For all the fields that need validation in both add:

`* @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"Default", "doctor"})`

For the phone field:

`* @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"Default"})`

Don't forget to set the correct validation group in the form:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/validation_groups.html

Comment: But in this case, I need to make a new form for each group I have ?

Comment: You can pass validation groups when creating the form or alter them in the form itself.